# How to get User details from LDAP or from Azure AD

Tags: json, asp.net-core, ldap, azure-web-app-service

An application, which was getting the user detail by calling a web service API. However, the web service recently stopped/decommissioned.

The way it **was** implemented to get the user details like below:

```
  [httpGet]
  Public WebServiceResponse GetUserInfo(string ID);
    {
       try
          {
             return 
                UsrMgr.GetTheUsersbyWS(ID,AuthorizationHeaderKey,AuthorizationHeaderValue,SearchURL);
          }
       Catch(Exception Ex)
          {
           }
    }
```

The "GetTheUsersbyWS" defind as :

```
  public WebServiceResponse GetTheUsersbyWS (string Id, string key, string val, string url)
  {
    //code lines
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebServiceResponse>(result);
  }
```

The "WebServiceResponse" class is as below:

```
   public class WebServiceResponse
       {
         public string id {get;set;}
         public string email {get;set;}
         public string cn {get;set;}
         public string role {get;set;}
         public string anyerror {get;set;}
       }
```

The "UsrMgr" is a property.

Considering decommissioned, below is how I'm trying to implement LDAP.

```
 [httpGet]
  Public WebServiceResponse GetUserInfo(string ID);
    {
       try
          {
             return 
                UsrMgr.GetTheUsers(ID);
          }
       Catch(Exception Ex)
          {
           }
    }
```

Here is the "GetTheUsers" method defination.

```
public WebServiceResponse GetTheUsers(string id)
 {
   string ldaphost = "localhost";
   int ldapport = 123;
   string ldapcredential = "the required details"
   string ldappass = "The password"
   LdapEntry nextEntry = null;
   LdapSearchresults result = null;
   try
     {
        LdapConnection lconn = new LdapConnection();
        string requiredattributes = {"id","email","cn","role"};
        lconn.Connect(ldaphost ,ldapport);
        lconn.Bind(ldapcredential ,ldappass );
        result = (LdapSearchresults)lconn.Search(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5);
        nextEntry = result.next(); //Getting data from LDAP - OK.
        lconn.Disconnect();
     }
     catch(LdapException e)
      {
           //message
      }
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebServiceResponse>(nextEntry.ToString()); // Here is the problem
 }
```

The new method "GetTheUsers" written to get details from LDAP is **getting the required data**, however, throws exception to the calling method. So there is a problem in "return" statement.

Does anyone faced such problem? Any clue/solution to resolve the issue? - may be by changing return statement and without changing the calling method.

The application is .net core and hosted in Azure app service. 2ndly, is there any ways to get the user details from Azure AD? If yes, what is the steps to do this?

Any of the ways; ( LDAP OR getting details from Azure AD) will help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about graph api? Microsoft provides [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-standard-users-request) to help developers obtain azure ad user information in `/users/userid` endpoint. Do I misunderstand in some way?

Comment: Thanks for the information. But the user id that is getting fetched is kind of big string which does not match with the company ID. I think, somehow it's converted/encoded to a different string. My program is getting real company user ID ( not the decoded one) from frontend; So, I'm thinking how can I address this issue? Additionally, from where can I get "AuthorizationHeaderKey and AuthorizationHeaderValue" ? Any example code  please?

Comment: Thanks for response, but according to the api doc, it only supports user id or `userPrincipalName`, such as Tiny@xxx.onmicrosoft.com. And even a guest user is not supported. https://i.stack.imgur.com/htnxI.png